What jokes were made in the dubbed versions of Deadpool & Wolverine regarding Chris Evans?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), various dubbed versions reportedly include clever in-jokes related to Chris Evans' appearance as Johnny Storm / the Human Torch, playing on the voice actors' history.
The German dub took an interesting approach:

In Germany, Ryan Reynolds and Chris Evans have the same voice actor. This was not always the case, Evans had a different one in the Fantastic Four movies. They actually brought that guy back, so when he's revealed to be Johnny, Deadpool says "I should have noticed by the voice."

The Latin American Spanish dub also got creative:

Something similar happened in the Latin American Spanish dub. Both Ryan Reynolds and Chris Evans share the same voice actor, but they actually kept the same guy to dub both. When he gets killed by Cassandra, Deadpool jokes he would’ve taken up the entire budget if they kept him around, in Spanish he says “Their voices would’ve made it confusing to know who was who”

For reference, Deadpool's jokes in the original English version were:

Not my favorite Chris.


Hey, we’re all grieving! P.S. Do you know what he was doing to the budget?

Other than the above, what other jokes were made in the dubbed versions of Deadpool & Wolverine regarding Chris Evans' appearance as Johnny Storm?
Are there any other clever localizations in different language versions?

I love they got some meta jokes into the dubbing too, great work.
